# How may I use a 3x3 matrix to simulate a larger square matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am using a game engine where the library only provides 3x3 matrices with the multiplication and inverse operation. I could build my own matrix library to provide larger matrices, but it would be less efficient to do so. Is there any clever mathematical way I could use 3x3 matrices with the limited operations they provide to easily simulate some larger square matrix?

Edit: Technically they do support other operations than the ones I mentioned (such as initialization from quaternion), but I wasn't sure of its relevance. You can view its documentation [here](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=CFrame).

Comment: Exactly what dimension matrix do you want to use? If it's a multiple of $3$, then [block matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix) could work. Also, this looks like Lua and just Googling "lua matrix library" gives me [Lua Matrix](http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaMatrix) and [Numeric Lua](http://numlua.luaforge.net/), so you might not need to build your own matrix library.

Comment: A 9x9 matrix would work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so it's been a *LONG* time since I've written Lua code, so I'm just going to write this as best as I can, but there might be syntax errors here. Basically, the way, we're going to represent a 9x9 matrix is as a 3x3 matrix of 3x3 matrices. This is called a [block matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix).

```
function block_matrix_sum(CFrame_matrix1, CFrame_matrix2):
    --[[
    CFrame_matrix1 and CFrame_matrix2 are both multi-dimensional 3x3
    arrays of CFrames, which I assume are 3x3 matrices.
    The return of this function is the product of these two matrices
    as 3x3 array of CFrames, just like the inputs.
    ]]--
    sum = {}
    for i=1,3 do
        --Add the ith row to sum:
        table.insert(sum, {})
        for j=1,3 do
            --Make the jth element of the ith row of the sum
            --simply the sum of the two corresponding elements in the inputs.
            table.insert(sum[i], CFrame_matrix1[i][j]+CFrame_matrix2[i][j])
        end
    end
    --Finally, return the sum.
    return sum

function block_matrix_multiplication(CFrame_matrix1, CFrame_matrix2):
    --[[
    CFrame_matrix1 and CFrame_matrix2 are both multi-dimensional 3x3
    arrays of CFrames, which I assume are 3x3 matrices.
    The return of this function is the product of these two matrices
    as 3x3 array of CFrames, just like the inputs.
    ]]--
    product = {}
    for i=1,3 do
        --Add the ith row to product:
        table.insert(product, {})
        for j=1,3 do
            --Add the jth element in the ith row to product:
            table.insert(product[i], CFrame.new(0, 0, 0))
            --Calculate this element of the matrix:
            for k=1,3 do
                product[i][j] += CFrame_matrix1[i][k]+CFrame_matrix2[k][j]
            end
        end
    end
    --Finally, return the product:
    return product
```

Inverses in block matrices are more complicated and I'm not quite sure how to do this with a 3x3 block partition.

Answer (score 0):

Block matrix multiplication will work.

$\begin{bmatrix} A&B\\ C&D\end{bmatrix}\cdot \begin{bmatrix} E&F\\G&H\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}AE+BG & AF+BH\\CE+DG&CF+DH\end{bmatrix}$

In the above, each of $A,B,\dots$ are matrices.  Say, for example $3\times 3$ matrices.  Building up from there, one could easily simulate products of matrices of dimensions which are multiples of three.  One could also use a row and column (or rows and columns) of all zeroes except a $1$ on the main diagonal to narrow it further to a nonmultiple of three.

Inverses will prove to be more of a challenge.

Given some conditions on the dimensions of each and the singularity of each matrix, (A must be square and invertible, (D-CA^{-1}B)$ must be invertible)

$\begin{bmatrix}A&B\\C&D\end{bmatrix}^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix} (A-BD^{-1}C)^{-1}&-A^{-1}B(D-CA^{-1}B)^{-1}\\-D^{-1}C(A-BD^{-1}C)^{-1}&(D-CA^{-1}B)^{-1}\end{bmatrix}$

Addition should be straightforward as well.